# Autorun gulp tasks in Visual Studio Code when opening workspace

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code, gulp-watch

Every time I open my project's workspace in Visual Studio Code, I have to manually press F1, write 'run task' and select my startup task to rebuild source code and initiate the debug web server/source-file watchers.

Is there a way to have Visual Studio Code auto-run this task for me when I open a workspace?

Like a 'default' task (seemed to work with Task Runner in Visual Studio 201x). Maybe there is some other naming-convention in Visual Studio Code that I'm not aware of (I've Googled a lot).

Comment: You could assign a hot-key sequence to run any task you want.  It won't run automatically whenever you open a workspace but would run with the hot-key sequence you assign.  Let me know if you want to see the code for such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin called [Blade Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yukidoi.blade-runner#overview) which does this. Only problem you need to stick to the default `run build task`. You can run different tasks inside the default one.